# Proving a linear functional is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis

Define $T:{l}^{\infty}\rightarrow l^{\infty}$ by

$$T(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(x_1,\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}x_j,\frac{1}{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}x_j,\dots)$$

We have to prove that $T$ is continuous.

I also have the following question: How do we know that $T(x_1,x_2,\dots)\in l^{\infty}$ ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

To show the operator is continuous, you need to show it's linear and bounded (this will imply Tx is in $l^\infty$ automatically, since $l^\infty$ is just the space of bounded sequences). Now take $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ s.t $||\{a_n\}||_\infty \leq 1$, e.g $\sup_n |a_n| \leq 1$. Consider that $\{T(\{a_n\})\}_j=\frac{1}{j}\sum_{i=1}^j a_i \leq \max_{1 \leq k \leq j} |a_k|$

in words, the average of $n$ numbers is always less than other equal to the largest of those numbers. Can you take it from here to show $||T(\{a_n\})||_{\infty} \leq 1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer (I tend not to give complete answers if all you give is a problem and "any ideas", rather I give an idea to start with)

Essentially, you are trying to prove 2 very similar things.   To be in $l^\infty$,  you need the elements to be bounded, i.e. $\exists M>0: \forall i \in \mathbb N, |\pi _i (T(x))|<M$, where $\pi_i$ is just the projection function giving the i'th component.  To prove continuity, you need to show another kind of bounding,  that $\forall x\in l^\infty$,  $\exists M>0$  such that $\|Tx\|_\infty \le \|x\|_\infty  $,  so you want to bound the supremum of the averages of elements by some scalar multiple of the supremum of the original elements.